Image from a <canvas> toBlob interpolates edges
I am trying to scale a 1x image up to an arbitrary size using a canvas. However, the image always has some interpolation at the edges of each pixel. I expect the image provided to match how the look canvas exactly. No combination of different scales etc. has worked for me. Even right click -> save image on the canvas produces the same image.
I have also tried using toDataURL on the canvas but I get the same result.
I see this on macOS with a 2x display. The same result in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.
The 2 side-by-side:

The produced image:



// This function is unimportant; it is used as an example for this question.
function generateImage(width, height, digitOffset) {
  const pixelsCount = width * height
  const imageData = new ImageData(width, height)
  const digits = "0123456789"
    .repeat(30)
    .substring(digitOffset, digitOffset + pixelsCount)

  for (const [index, digit] of [...digits].entries()) {
    const colours = {
      0: [0x00, 0x12, 0x19],
      1: [0x00, 0x5f, 0x73],
      2: [0x0a, 0x93, 0x96],
      3: [0x94, 0xd2, 0xbd],
      4: [0xe9, 0xd8, 0xa6],
      5: [0xee, 0x9b, 0x00],
      6: [0xca, 0x67, 0x02],
      7: [0xbb, 0x3e, 0x03],
      8: [0xae, 0x20, 0x12],
      9: [0x9b, 0x22, 0x26],
    }
    const dataOffset = index * 4

    const color = colours[digit]
    imageData.data[dataOffset] = color[0]
    imageData.data[dataOffset + 1] = color[1]
    imageData.data[dataOffset + 2] = color[2]
    imageData.data[dataOffset + 3] = 0xff
  }

  return imageData
}

/** The width/height of the 1x image. */
const size = 16
const imageData = generateImage(size, size, 0)
const scale = 10
/** The canvas containing the 1x image. */
const unscaledCanvas = document.getElementById("unscaledCanvas")
unscaledCanvas.width = size
unscaledCanvas.height = size
unscaledCanvas.style.width = `${size}px`
unscaledCanvas.style.height = `${size}px`
const unscaledContext = unscaledCanvas.getContext("2d")
unscaledContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)

const scaledCanvas = document.getElementById("increasedScale")
scaledCanvas.width = size * scale
scaledCanvas.height = size * scale
scaledCanvas.style.width = `${size * scale}px`
scaledCanvas.style.height = `${size * scale}px`
scaledCanvas.style.imageRendering = "pixelated"
const scaledContext = scaledCanvas.getContext("2d")
scaledContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
scaledContext.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false
scaledContext.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false
scaledContext.drawImage(unscaledCanvas, 0, 0, size * scale, size * scale)

const image = document.getElementById("output")
image.width = size * scale
image.height = size * scale
scaledCanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
  const dataURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  image.onload = () => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(dataURL)
  }
  image.src = dataURL
})
<canvas id="unscaledCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="increasedScale"></canvas>
<img id="output" />




Set the width and height before setting the imageSmoothingEnabled. The one in doc seemed to work because of the CSS image-rendering but that's not exported.

I have edited the question to set the size before imageSmoothingEnabled but hasn't changed.
The duplicate question relates to setting the size of the context, but here the size is being set on the canvas itself. Also note that it does render correctly in the browser; it's only when exported to an image that it interpolates.

Looks good to me. Note that there the size was also set on the canvas, there is no size for a context, and also note that imageSmoothingEnabled is a 2D context property, all your scaledCanvas.XXXimageSmoothingEnabled don't do anything. But anyways, your snippet shows correctly for me, neither the canvas nor the  show any antialiasing

I've added a screenshot of what it looks like for me. I've also removed setting XXXimageSmoothingEnabled on the canvas -- thanks for pointing that out.

Ok, so that's just how your browser renders this image on a 2x monitor. The actual image doesn't have the antialiasing artifacts. You can see this by drawing it to a 3rd canvas upscaled: https://jsfiddle.net/nvq15efp/ (Note that for this canvas I took care of avoiding the resizing issue by resizing the #zoom canvas width and height based on the current dPR, while downscaling through CSS. For <img>, you could serve multiple density through the srcset attribute, or use theimage-rendering CSS property like you did for your canvas.

The image does not have the antialiasing artifacts you're seeing encoded in it, your browser creates these when upscaling the image to match your 2x monitor's pixel density.
We can prove that by drawing this same image upscaled again on another <canvas>:


(async () => {
  // using OP's produced image
  const resp = await fetch("https://i.sstatic.net/7oZk5oeK.png");
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  // Make the canvas the correct density
  canvas.width *= devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height *= devicePixelRatio; 
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
  // no smoothing
  ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  // upscale
  ctx.scale(10, 10);
  ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
})().catch(console.error);
canvas { width: 300px; height: 150px; }
<canvas></canvas>



Note that for this canvas I took care of avoiding the resizing issue by resizing the <canvas>'s  width and height based on the current dPR, while downscaling it through CSS.
To render your image correctly in an <img>, you could prepare multiple versions with different density and then use the srcset attribute of your <img>:


<img 
  width=160 height=160
  srcset="
    https://i.sstatic.net/7oZk5oeK.png,
    https://i.sstatic.net/OlFcowA1.png 2x,
    https://i.sstatic.net/QsWfkvSn.png 3x,
  ">



Or you could use the same image-rendering CSS rule you used on your <canvas>:


img { image-rendering: pixelated }
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/7oZk5oeK.png">




That's exactly it, what a silly mistake! ‍♂️ despite acocunting for it in other places I was accounting for CSS pixels not being the same as physical pixels here.
